# Reload a .js file on selectedindex change event of dropdown in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a dropdown inside update panel. On the selected index change event, i need to execute a .js file using c# or javascript
How can i do this ?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Social_Ddl" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <div class="styled-select">
      <asp:Label runat="server" 
         ID="Label2" 
         Font-Size="Small" 
         ToolTip="Social : 'ON' will post your activity on this page to your FaceBook Wall."   Text="Social :" 
         Style="vertical-align: bottom;" />
          <asp:DropDownList 
             ID="ddlSocialSwitch" 
             runat="server" 
             AutoPostBack="true" 
             Style="vertical-align: middle;" 
              ToolTip="Social : ON will post your activity on this page to your FaceBook Wall."   
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSocialSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged">
          </asp:DropDownList>
       &nbsp;<a valign="bottom" onclick="logout_fb" href="#" id="auth-logoutlink"><img valign="bottom" src="facebookLogOutButton.png"/></a>
       <asp:Label ID="lbl" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: you don't execute js files. So which is it? you need to dynamically load a js file or execute a javascript function in a js file?

Comment: @Hardrada On selecting the value in dropdown, i need to execute the .js file again to perform some validation on the page. During the change event of dropdown, i found that the .js file is not executed again. So i need to manually execute the .js file again for each selected index change event.

Comment: @Hardrada When the page loads the .js file is executed properly, since it is referenced in my page. But on selecting a value in dropdown, the .js file dosent load. Thats why i want to manually execute the js file again

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mean "function" and not "file". Assuming that, I see that you have a click handler on the auth-logoutlink. update panels will "destroy" the event handler because of how it recreates the DOM when the data is returned. You have to reattach the onclick event to that link.